# Getting a list of all requested fixtures in pytest at the end of a test

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have the following sample code:

```
# In my conftest.py
@pytest.mark.fixture(scope="function")
def func_fix():
    ...

@pytest.mark.fixture(scope="session")
def sess_fix():
    ...

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    # HELP NEEDED

# In my test code:
def test_foo(sess_fix, func_fix):
    ...
```

I'd like to take action in pytest_unconfigure based on whether `func_fix()` was requested or not. Within another fixture which gets `request`, I can check `request.fixturenames`, but I'm not sure how I can do this in pytest_unconfigure(). My current solution involves setting `config.foo = bar` in `func_fix()`, and then checking that in `pytest_unconfigure()`, which works assuming everything is good.

The problem is that when `sess_fix()` fails, the `config.foo = bar` obviously hasn't been set, so I can't take action in `pytest_unconfigure()`.

I  don't need `func_fix()` to actually have ran. I just need to know that the user wanted to run it.

EDIT: I admit I'm kind of abusing finalizers here. I would also welcome any suggestions for a better way to handle teardown functions.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not add a finalizer/teardown to `func_fix` specifically?